# Grouping by Continents in Leaflet.js geoJSON

Tags: javascript, html, maps, leaflet

I have a geoJson data layer of the world from naturalearthdata.com and a working map based on countries (features) with hover colors setup.  I want to group the data on continents, so I'd end up with Europe, Americas, Aftrica and Middle East, Asia & Australia.

There doesn't seem to be any examples of this - I wouldn't think I need to change the data since all countries have the continent property. Whats best practice to achieve this?

Comment: What do you _exactly_ mean by "group"?? Do you mean ["dissolve"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71612/dissolve-polygons-in-qgis-geos-with-tolerance)??

Comment: I would like to end up with one area for each continent, so one hover event, one label etc.  If I can make that up from the same data, i.e. using the features continent property then that would be great.  I'm not worried about dissolving the boundaries, more to group the features by continent.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update, I decided to alter the .shp file in QGIS and merge the individual features to make these larger regions.  Took a load of tidying up stray lines with the Node tool but this produced what I needed.